# Extract text around a list of words in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to extract a few lines (perhaps 100 or so characters) of text from text files. I have a list of words that I would like to extract around. I have the following code that does exactly what I want it to do except sometimes the lines are not long enough to capture everything I need.

```
import os

ngwrds=[long list of words]

for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        with open(filename, 'r') as searchfile:
            for line in searchfile:
                if any(x in line for x in ngwrds):
                    with open("extract.txt", 'a') as out:
                        out.write("{} {} \n".format(filename, line))
```

Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is "everything you need" to capture?

Comment: So, if you want to capture the 10 words around word `x`, and `x` appears as the third word in line `n`, you also want the last 7 words from line `n-1`? If the files are not too big, how about just joining the lines?